# Issues with gettext php

Tags: php, locale, gettext

Text translation via gettext does not work. Help me please

```
$translate = 'messages';

putenv("LC_ALL=en_US");
T_setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");

bindtextdomain($translate, _ROOT_DIR_."locale/");
textdomain($translate);
bind_textdomain_codeset($translate, 'UTF-8');
```

Folder structure:

> locale ->
>               en_US ->
>                       LC_MESSAGES ->
>                                       messages.mo
>                                       messages.po

Script messages.po :

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-05-03 15:53+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2017-05-03 15:54+0300\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.1\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: en_US\n"

#: index.php:5
msgid "Bonjour tout le monde"
msgstr "Hello world"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify in which respect gettext "does not work". Include any error messages and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you're on Windows, I'm pretty sure you're going to be SOL... if you're in *nix, remember you'll need to restart Apache after making any changes in the .po files.

Comment: I tuned: .po and .mo files, locale, domain, and the text is still not translated
No errors are showing
Every time after modifying .po I restart open serever

Comment: what means "going to be SOL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had to comment out one line in the php.ini file. Like this -

```
;extension=php_gettext.dll
```